# How to get the Id of clicked element in a WebKit view?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I have a `UIWebKit` loaded in an url and I want to pick the id of a html element when clicked. I can get the element when I know the id but how to get an unknown element Id when it is clicked. 
thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it following way.

1. Inject some javascript into the WebView using `WKUserScript`.
2. Injected javascript will listen to document body for any click event.
3. Upon an click event received, find the DOM element using `elementFromPoint`.
4. Setup that way, javascript will communicate with native code.
5. Upon receiving clicks and finding the element, contact native code for clicked DOM.

I've tested this way of working & it works for me.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    private var url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initializeWebView()
        loadData()

    }

    private func initializeWebView() {

        let javascript = """
        window.onload = function() {
            document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
                var tagClicked = document.elementFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsMessenger.postMessage(tagClicked.outerHTML.toString());
            });
        }
        """

        let userScript = WKUserScript.init(source: javascript,
                                           injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
        webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsMessenger")
    }

    private func loadData() {
        let request  = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView?.load(URLRequest.init(url: url))
    }
}


extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print(message.body)
    }
}
```

It gives you the whole element as string

Comment: Very clear answer ! you saved me a lot of time man thank you !

Comment: As it helps, consider putting a upvote as you already accepted the answer.

Comment: This answer works! But as written, the `addEventListener` will not fire if you tap a button within the page, because the button has its own click behavior. Add `true` after the event listener function to enable `useCapture` which causes the event listener to fire before the button action, thus reporting the button tap back to the view controller. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var webContentView: UIView!
var web: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let JSsource =  """
    window.onload = function() {
        document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
            var tagClicked = document.elementFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsMessenger.postMessage(tagClicked.outerHTML.toString());
        });
    }
    """

     let script = WKUserScript(source: JSsource, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
     config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
    config.userContentController.add(self as! WKScriptMessageHandler, name: "jsMessenger")

    self.web = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height-60), configuration : config)

    self.web.navigationDelegate = self
    self.web.uiDelegate = self
    self.webContentView.addSubview(self.web!)
  }
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print(message.body)
}
```